# Meaning of "result segment" in CloudQueueClient Class

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have seen many reference mentioning the term "result segment" in CloudQueueClient Class, such as in methods "ListQueuesSegmented" and "ListQueuesSegmentedAsync". But I failed to find any meaningful example on how to use these functions. Could any Azure expert explain?

Thanks

Derek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a storage account, you can create an unlimited number of queues inside(see [storage limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#storage-limits) for more information).

Let say you want to get information about all the queues, you can use the [`CloudQueueClient.ListQueues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682327.aspx) method to iterate through all your queues :

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("MyConnectionString");
var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
foreach(var queue in queueClient.ListQueues())
{
    // Do something
}
```

Imagine you have a thousand queues, you may not want to perform this request because it can timeout, reach some limits.

That all the purpose of the **`Segmented`** methods. It will return the first X elements + a token that allows you to request for the next X elements.

When you use tables to display data (on the UI side), sometimes you have to use pagination because your table may be too large to be displayed entirely: This the same concept.

So now if you want to use it:

```
// Initialize a new token
var continuationToken = new QueueContinuationToken();

// Execute the query
var segment = queueClient.ListQueuesSegmented(continuationToken);

// Get the new token in order to get the next segment
continuationToken = segment.ContinuationToken;

// Get the results
var queues = segment.Results.ToList();

// do something
...


// Execute the query again with the comtinuation token to fetch next results
segment = queueClient.ListQueuesSegmented(continuationToken);
```

Answer (score 3):

there are examples of how to use these functions at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-queue-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/QueueStorage/Advanced.cs

The particular one for how to page through the ListQueuesSegmentedAsync is: (note initializing to a null token appears to be correct, as is detecting a null token for ending the chain)

```
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine("List of queues in the storage account:");

        // List the queues for this storage account 
        QueueContinuationToken token = null;
        List<CloudQueue> cloudQueueList = new List<CloudQueue>();

        do
        {
            QueueResultSegment segment = await cloudQueueClient.ListQueuesSegmentedAsync(token);
            token = segment.ContinuationToken;
            cloudQueueList.AddRange(segment.Results);
        }
        while (token != null);
```